# WCF Service throwing error in WCF Service Host

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, iis, compiler-errors, hosting

I'm having some trouble with a WCF Service. When I host it in IIS, it runs fine, but I figure there is a problem somewhere.

When I run my WCF Service in Visual Studio 2010, it brings up the WCF Service Host.

It names the host, then the status is 'Error'.

The error it gave is this:

```
System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/EvalServiceLibrary/Service1/. Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix 'http://+:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/EvalServiceLibrary/Service1/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.
```

I don't know if this has affected the service deployed in IIS, since that tells me I have created a service if I browse it through IIS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty clear, the address is already in use.

Does the service in IIS run on the same port? Change it, or change your port for the development.